# What the best way to get structured array / dataframe like structures in Numba?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jit, numba

I have a numpy array that I reference by column, e.g., `df['x']`, `df['y']`.

What is the best way to give this to Numba so I can run the function in `nopython` mode?

Or what is the best way to deal with dataframes in Numba, so I can access a column by name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Supply 1d arrays as arguments

`numba` is designed to work with NumPy arrays directly. So you should not look to feed a dataframe or structured array to a `numba` function. You can feed the arrays as separate arguments. For example:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def func(A, B):
    # some logic
    arr = A + B
    return arr

df['z'] = func(df['x'].values, df['y'].values)
```

#### Unpack 2d array within `numba` function

This is a special case where your dataframe series all have the same type. Check `df.dtypes` if you are not sure of your series types. You can feed a single array and perform the unpacking within `numba`:

```
@njit
def func(df_values):
    A, B = df_values[:, 0], df_values[:, 1]
    # some logic
    arr = A + B
    return arr

df['z'] = func(df[['x', 'y']].values)
```